# Is ‘hallöchen’ appropriate between a professor and a student?

Tags: word-usage, formality, salutation

Can a teacher greet his students with *hallöchen*? 
May I use this word to say hello to my German boss when he comes to our office?
I see it’s informal but I would like to ask about the communicative strategy: what kind of people do we use this word for?

Comment: Erstaunlich! 16 (sic!) Votes auf dieser Frage! :)

Answer (score 25):

Generally speaking - no.

I would only use this greeting in very informal situations, and the minimum requirement would be that I say "Du" to the other person.

Nowadays, what is considered acceptable varies a lot with company culture - this also goes for universities/individual professors - so there is no hard and fast rule here. But generally speaking, you would have to be quite comfortable and informal with the other person to use it. Typically, this would be your friends.

If German is not your native language, I would suggest not to use the expression, unless your boss/professor has used it towards you first - getting those cultural connotations right is tricky even for Germans :)

Comment: You are right and in my opinion it tries to convey a hipster / cool vibe. I have collaborated with one such professor. I found it very undignified and it should have been my first clue of his lax, chaotic, toddleresque working style, which I came to hate.@Maya

Comment: Even if my boss or professor used it, I would still greet them with "Hallo" and never with "Hallöchen". "Hallöchen" sounds far too silly for a professional relationship.

Comment: @Iris "Hallöchen" sounds silly in general. :)) Would consider myself "dämlich" using it to whoever.

Comment: I'm trying to think of an English equivalent of "hallöchen".  Would " 'sup" (as in "What's up") be a fair comparison?

Comment: @BruceWayne: "Howdily Doodily" or something inane like that. " 'sup?" is more for "Was geht ab?"/"Was ist los?"/"Wie geht's?"

Comment: @yatima2975 - Thanks for that! And jaaaaaa, now I can be Ned Flanders auf Deutsch!

Comment: @BruceWayne, you could also say "Halli hallo hallöchen"